# How to view log of user actions

Tags: google-app-maker

Is there way to view (or create) a log of users actions? Like who created/edited/deleted an item?

ex: I need to be able to see that "User A" changed the "Status Dropdown" from "In Progress" to "Complete" on 7/11/17 at 4pm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Model has [events](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/events#onsave_example), so you can log user actions in this events:

```
**console.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() + " updated status from " + record.status + " to " + oldRecord.status);**
```

Comment: Is there a way I can tell it to make note of the user/item(s) that changed? Something like, console.log(currentUserEmail "has changed the status to" currentStatus);  ?

Comment: onSave event
console.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() + "updated status from" record.status + "to" + oldRecord.status)

Comment: Thank you! Had to adjust it slightly to include a missing "+". **console.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() + " updated status from " + record.status + "to" + oldRecord.status);**. Everything seems to work expect it returns "record.status" and "oldrecord.status" as "undefined" (ex: "adam@emailaddress.com updated status from undefined to undefined". I am maybe missing an option for the Model to make a record when an item is created/changed?

Comment: What is status column name?

Comment: Ahhhh. The "S" is capitalized. Changed to "Status" and everything working. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Check out Project Tracker template(https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/project-tracker/), it demonstrates how to persist record changes in database.

Hovever you can log your actions using

```
// Server script
console.log('Your log entry goes here')
```

You can view your deployment logs by clicking View Logs button on the deployment card:
[image]